# How to know how many instance of my discord bot are running

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, rate-limiting

I am working on a discord bot but it often gets rate limited, I think its because of multiple instances of my bot, I have 2 instance of bot purposely but I think there might be other instances which are causing Discord to Rate Limit my bot, is there any way to know how many instances my bot is running so I can prevent rate limit? I have tried `kill 1` but it is just a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to find out how many instances are running other than doing it manually. For example, add a command which tells you the information about the current instance, and it will be run for all instances of the bot.

A good practise is to have different instances on different bot accounts for easier differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

alright so, you can add a command in your script which wait till you send specific command, when you send the command you can use socket(you can use any other network package if needed) package to send tcp packet to a specific server(you can use ngrok), and when you recive these packets to the server you can just count how many packet came to your http server.